# How do backslashes work in double-quoted format strings passed to printf?

Tags: bash, printf

In bash.

```
bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

debian8@debian:~$ printf "%-5s\n"  "hah"
hah
```

Simple ,to have a newline with **\n**

```
debian8@debian:~$ printf "%-5s\\n"  "hah"
hah
```

because **`\\=\`** , **printf "%-5s\n"  "hah"  ==  printf "%-5s\n"  "hah"**

```
debian8@debian:~$ printf "%-5s\\\n"  "hah"
hah  \ndebian8@debian:~$
```

It is **\n** literally,why no newline?
Why not   \=\  -->  \\=\=\  -->  \\n=\n=\n  ?

And i am confused by the following  multiple  escaping action.

```
debian8@debian:~$ printf "%-5s\\\\n"  "hah"
hah  \ndebian8@debian:~$ printf "%-5s\\\\\n"  "hah"
hah  \
debian8@debian:~$ printf "%-5s\\\\\\n"  "hah"
hah  \
```

Please make an explanation in detail.

Comment: There is extra interpolation going on because you are using double quotes.  Try using single quotes and note the difference.

Comment: This is all direct consequence of explicitly documented behavior of double-quoted strings in POSIX shells in general -- nothing about it at all is specific to `printf`. Could you update the question in a way that makes it clear that you've done your homework on the general behavior of backslash-escape sequences in double quotes, and still have questions? Otherwise, answering this question requires combining two separate explanations (of backslash escapes in double quotes, and of `printf`) rather than being scoped to a single topic.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
1.There are two escapes here,first escaping by " ;second escaping by printf .
2. **`\\ = \`** literally ,which has no escaping function.
3. the escaping result by " at first passed into printf,to go on escaping for the second time at the same rule as the second point.

Comment: "none", vs `\n`, for `\n` in double quotes?

Comment: none means no escaping action ,"\n" in double quotes is newline.

Comment: That's untrue, as you can easily test for yourself: `s="\n"; printf '%s\n' "$s"` prints the literal string `\n`, with a backslash the first character and an `n` the second. (By contrast, `$'\n'` is a literal newline, and `s=$'\n'; printf '%s\n' "$s"` prints two newlines -- one from the format string, one from the variable's literal value).

Comment: (I actually dispute that "escaping by `printf`"` is an accurate description of anything that happens at all, but that's... perhaps a larger discussion. Perhaps you mean *unescaping*?)